# Rigorous Construction of $e^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider :
$$
E(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}
$$
Based on some derivations from the binomial theorem, we note that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$ and $E(x)E(-x)=1$. We must show that $E(n)=e^{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and we must show that $E(k)=e^{k}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Any hint?

Comment: What is your starting definition of $e$?

Comment: For *some*? Sure about that?

Comment: We have that $E(1)=e$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I fixed it thanks!

Comment: So it is $(E(1))^{n}$? that is to say $(E(1)+0)^{n}$?

Comment: $E(n+1)=E(n)E(1)$ so use induction.  Then use $E(-n)=\frac{1}{E(n)}$

Comment: Just what I thought thank you Henry! @Henry. For the second part it also follows by induction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $E(1)=e=e^1$, you can now prove by induction that $^(\forall n\in\Bbb N):E(n)=e^n$. On the other hand, $E(0)=1$ and therefore $E(x)E(-x)=1$; in other words, $E(x)=\frac1{E(-x)}$. And now, if $k\in\Bbb Z$ and $k<0$,$$E(k)=\frac1{E(-k)}=\frac1{e^{-k}}=e^k.$$